# Xcode 5.1.1 and Boost

Tags: c++, boost

## Problem was solved by adding .dylib files (boost) to project.

I'm trying connect Boost 1.55 to Xcode 5 through Homebrew. 
Brew installed it as it should. In /usr/local/include && /usr/local/lib appeared aliases on Boost headers and libraries.

Xcode "Search Path" settings: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/itW83.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO0n9.png

But when I tried compile simple example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

    int main()
    {
        const regex expression( "How to re" );

        string string1 = "How to re";

        bool match=regex_match(string1,expression);

        if (match){
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "boost::basic_regex >
>
> > ::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
> >           boost::basic_regex > >::assign(char const*, char const*,
> >     unsigned int) in main.o   "boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()",
> >     referenced from:
> >           boost::re_detail::perl_matcher,
> >     std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits >
> >     ::extend_stack() in main.o
> >           boost::re_detail::save_state_init::save_state_init(boost::re_detail::saved_state**,
> >     boost::re_detail::saved_state**) in main.o
> >     "boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)", referenced from:
> >           boost::re_detail::save_state_init::~save_state_init() in main.o
> >           boost::re_detail::perl_matcher,
> >     std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits >
> >     ::unwind_extra_block(bool) in main.o   "boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int,
> >     boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
> >           boost::re_detail::perl_matcher,
> >     std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits >
> >     ::match_imp() in main.o   "boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)",
> >     referenced from:
> >           void boost::re_detail::raise_error > >
> >     (boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > const&,
> >     boost::regex_constants::error_type) in main.o
> >     "boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)",
> >     referenced from:
> >           boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)
> >     const in main.o
> >     "boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
> >           boost::cpp_regex_traits::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const in main.o
> >     "boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform(char
> >     const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
> >           boost::cpp_regex_traits::transform(char const*, char const*) const in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
> >     x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
> >     see invocation)

Really tired with it, so, ask for your help.

Thank you,
 - Philipp

Comment: I didn't see it in the screenshots, but did you link in boost either with `-l` or manually in Xcode?

Comment: No. Can you tell me, how can I do this?

Comment: I don't know what options homebrew uses for building boost, but see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library for more help.  If you post the contents of /usr/local/lib that will help also.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RiXmwHGP
All of these files — aliases. After I had added .dylib files of boost libraries, it started work. But, as I know, with brew installing I shouldn't add any files to project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options but all of them involve adding the library `libboost_regex` to your project to resolve the link errors.  Even though you installed boost using homebrew, you still need to add the library to your project because boost's regex code contains a compiled portion.  If you don't add the library there is no way for the linker to resolve the symbols.

The first option is to add `/usr/local/lib` to *Library Search Paths*, and add `-lboost_regex` to *Other Linker Flags*.  If you choose this option you may need to add `/usr/local/lib` to *Runpath Search Paths* also.  This method will link against the dynamic library in `/usr/local/lib`.

If you want your program to be self-contained you can link against the static (`.a`) version of `boost_regex`.  To do this add `libboost_regex.a` to your project in *Build Settings* - *Link Binary With Libraries*.